# Lead fields that aren't traceable

Tags: history-tracking

I would like to history track a field called "Campaign" (in Lead Object) which is a lookup field type to "Campaign" Object (campaign name). Why this is not available to be marked up as traceable?

Could I used a workaround instead? (i.e. create other field which will get the same value as "Campaign" field ) and make this traceable?

Comment: HI bobirobobiro bobiro, Did you happen to solve this issue? Is there any feasible workaround for this scenario?

Answer (score 2):

The reason `Campaign` is not history trackable is because the field doesn't really exist on the Lead object as you can see in the [SObject doc](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_lead.htm?search_text=user).

One Lead can be on many campaigns via the `CampaignMember` junction object.

The field you see in the UI is a convenience field that SFDC provides to the page layout. From the [Help doc](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=leads_fields.htm&language=en_US):

> Name of the campaign responsible for generating the lead. Displays only when creating a new lead. Data entered in this field is stored in the Campaign History related list on the lead

Answer (score 0):

Campaign object does not have history tracking enabled and hence I guess none of the objects referencing lookups to this object has ability to track fields .

The workaround you have should definitely work but with an overhead of maintaining a process builder flow or a trigger to keep the fields in sync.